# Group ID is the key. How to take queries from one group and append them to another

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to avoid PHP because I'm not that experienced, but if I have to I will. I have a table of reports that has a lot of information, including a key known as the group_id. There was a problem where a customer accidentally created two users, so two group_id's, and now their data is split between the two group_id's.

I need to merge all of the data under one group_id. We have chosen the lead group_id to be 109, and the other one they have is 110.

I can grab all the reports from group_id 110 with this query:

```
    select * from reports where group_id = 110
```

What I need to do is change all of these queries group id's to 109.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an `update`:

```
update reports r
    set group_id = 109
    where group_id = 110;
```

Note:  this changes the data in the table itself, so the change is permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as Gordon Linoff said.

```
    update reports r
    set group_id = 109
    where group_id = 110;
```

Comment: Mark his answer as a solution and remove this answer.